How to disable iOS autofil and share button on tapping readonly input field
iOS 17 shows Autofil (and Share) option on the top left of the screen on tapping readonly input.

This fiddle can be used to reproduce the behavior.
https://jsfiddle.net/armujahid/p3d6yxu8/
<input type="text" placeholder="This is a readonly input" value="some content" readonly>
You can

tap on "some content" readonly input to check that behavior
you can also select a date and then tap on that date input to reproduce that weird behavior since date input is also readonly. (This is the actual issue I am trying to solve. point 1 is just MCVE. )

How can we disable this behavior? I have already tried adding autocomplete="off" and autocorrect="off" but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
Note that this isn't restricted to safari and occurs in other browsers only on iOS. Of course other platforms like android and desktop doesn't have this issue.
